# Remove nodes after filtering

Tags: gephi

So I am making a [Gephi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gephi) graph and wants to make some subgraphs using filters.

After filtering the nodes using intra edges(based in group) I get some lonely nodes, so I want to remove them: Library->Topology-> Degree range

So theoretically, all those unused nodes should be removed.

But because degree range still stays at 1-32, and no 0 is found, I can't remove the nodes.

I tried different combinations but it just doesn't work somehow. [Here is one of the nodes I want to remove because it has 0 in and out degree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ3p6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tough one because you need to recompute degrees for the filtered graph. I would recommend the following approach:

1. Copy your current degree columns to something like `[in|out|degree]_global` so that they don't get overwritten by step 2
2. Copy your filtered graph to a new workspace (or save the *visible graph only*)
3. Recompute the degrees on the filtered graph
4. Filter by range as you do now